# Codeigniter populate a table from database

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, foreach, html-table

I want to populate all the data from my database to a table using `<?php foreach; ?>` but I can't get it to work. Please check my code:

```
controller
$data['query'] = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM users');
$this->load->view('users_view',$data);

View
<?php foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{ ;?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['usrID'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['usrName'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['usrPassword'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: You've got `{...}` after the `foreach`, and you also have `endforeach` - only use one or the other. In template files I find `foreach(...):` and `endforeach;` nicest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would reccommend the alternative syntax for your foreach in the view...

It looks like you should be having some syntax errors the way you have it.

```
<?php foreach ($query->result_array() as $row): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['usrID'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['usrName'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['usrPassword'];?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

***EDIT*** - to point out your syntax issues.

```
<?php foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{ ;?> //<---- semicolon?
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['usrID'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['usrName'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['usrPassword'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?> //<--- no need for this when using regular foreach
```

This first semicolon would be like writing a foreach like this...

```
foreach ($array as $ele) { ; //<--this would throw an error just like it should above.
    //do stuff
}
```

***Opinion aside from the point of the question***

You should be processing your data in the controller and simply sending an array of data to be displayed in the view, not the whole query object.

so...

Controller

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM users');
$data['users'] = $query->result_array();
$this->load->view('users_view',$data);
```

Comment: Type: Error

Message: Call to a member function result_array() on array